# Custom RoleProvider and Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following along with the tutorial on [this site](http://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc).

While attempting to implement the Custom RoleProvider I am getting the following error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this
request. Please review the specific error details below and modify
your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: This
method cannot be called during the application's pre-start
initialization phase
```

Source Error:

```
<providers>
    <clear/> 
    <add name="MyroleProvider"type="MvcApplication1.Infrastructure.MyroleProvider"con ectionStringName="DatabaseContext" applicationName="/" />
</providers>
```

I've updated the web.config section to following and I am still getting the error.

```
<roleManager enabled="true"  cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="MyroleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
   <add name="MyroleProvider" type="MvcApplication1.Infrastructure.MyroleProvider" connectionStringName="DatabaseContext" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<providers>
    <clear/> 
    <add name="MyroleProvider" type="MvcApplication1.Infrastructure.MyroleProvider" connectionStringName="DatabaseContext" applicationName="/" />
    . . .
</providers>
```

Isn't that more like the XML you wanted to type ? It is not identitical to

```
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="MyroleProvider"type="MvcApplication1.Infrastructure.MyroleProvider"con ectionStringName="DatabaseContext" applicationName="/" />
```

The word connection is segmented.

Comment: Oh and moreover, to avoid errors, format your XML/XAML/JSON/Anything.

It is the most basic thing a developer should do. to have something compact, use an obfuscator or an compacter.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved.
I defined empty project and attempted to implement the Custom RoleProvider. 
error resolved.